# Having trouble getting the value parameters into a stored procedure

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So right now i have a view, this view is being called by a table model as shown below. then in my controller I have a simple load model procedure and then set the values to transcript and whereterm " needed for a check " as shown below.

```
**inside my view**
    public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setTable('admin.vCalcTranscriptUpdateTerms');       
}

   **Inside my controller before the stored procedure call**
    $transcriptsTable = $this->loadModel('UpdatedTranscripts');

    $transcript = $transcriptsTable->find()->first();

    $this->set('transcript',$transcript);
    $this->set('whereTerm',$transcript);
```

After this is used i then move to my ctp file which is my display and have a bunch of P elements displaying the information as shown below. which works 100% the way i want it to and accurately.

```
**Inside my .ctp file :**
<p value="<?= $transcript->whereTerm; ?><?= $transcript->updateTerm; ? 
>">This 
will update the transcript term from
<?= $transcript->whereTerm; ?> to <?= $transcript->updateTerm; 
?></p>

<p value="<?= $transcript->schoolYear; ?>">School Year: <?= $transcript- 
>schoolYear; ?></p>

<p value="<?= $transcript->FiscalYear; ?>">Fiscal Year: <?= $transcript- 
>FiscalYear; ?></p>
```

Finally i have my controller and calling the stored procedure. Why is it the values i passed into the P elements are not being gathered from the getData request? when i inspect the page the value"" is showing the correct passed information and yet it is not being passed into my procedure as a parameter. this is very frustrating what do i need to do in order to fix this?

```
**Inside my controller**
        $postedData = $this->request->getData();

        $dbConnection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

        $results = $dbConnection
        ->execute(
            'exec admin.vCalcTranscriptUpdateTermsProcedure
                            @schoolYear=:schoolYear,
                            @FiscalYear=:FiscalYear,
                            @whereTerm=:whereTerm,
                            @updateTerm=:updateTerm
                        ',
                    [
                        'schoolYear' => $postedData['schoolYear'],
                        'FiscalYear' => $postedData['FiscalYear'],
                        'whereTerm' => $postedData['whereTerm'],
                        'updateTerm' => $postedData['updateTerm'],

                    ],
                    [
                        'schoolYear' => 'string',
                        'FiscalYear' => 'smallinteger',
                        'whereTerm' => 'integer',
                        'updateTerm' => 'integer',
                    ]
```

the results would be it successfully returning the rows effected but it errors way before that ever happens.

Edit - if i add something like this above it does not save the values to to session either ugg

```
        $this->request->getSession()->write('App.www',$this->request->getData());
```

Here are some errors i am getting when i try to load the webpage, it is saying nothing is defined well why the heck aren't the values be retrieved when i use get data before my stored procedure.

Notice (8): Undefined index: schoolYear [APP/Controller\UpdatedTranscriptsController.php, line 35]
Notice (8): Undefined index: FiscalYear [APP/Controller\UpdatedTranscriptsController.php, line 36]
Notice (8): Undefined index: whereTerm [APP/Controller\UpdatedTranscriptsController.php, line 37]
Notice (8): Undefined index: updateTerm [APP/Controller\UpdatedTranscriptsController.php, line 38]
Database Error
PDOException
Documentation API
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Procedure vCalcTranscriptUpdateTermsProcedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: You probably need to add more context... how are attributes in `<p>` elements supposed to be submitted? We don't know whether you might use JS, and we don't know what data exactly arrives at the server. And if you receive any errors, please post them (including the stacktrace from the log files).

Comment: I think you should also describe/separate what's in your view file and what's in your controller file

Comment: alright i made another edit

Comment: The errors indicate that no such fields exist in the post data... back to my initial remark, how are the `<p>` element attribute values supposed to be submitted as POST data from your frontend?

Comment: there suppose to be submitted as if ($this->request->is(['post','put'])). the values are being used in a update script written in sql like, so i need the values submitted via stored procedure

are you asking how am i suppose to get the values via data? wouldn't this get the P element data?         $postedData = $this->request->getData();
and then you use that post = to loops through the array for the values yout?

Comment: I am asking how the frontend submits the data to your backend? `<p>` elements aren't [**submittable elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#submittable-element), only `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, `<button>` and `<object>` are.

Comment: funny enough i actually found a article saying the exact same and since it already looked nice i decided to just implement hidden inputs into my html at the ent like 4 of them with the set values and it worked. unreal 2 hours of time all i had to do was change a little

Comment: Yes, if this is some kind of a confirmation page, then hidden inputs are a good way to go. Might want to do a bit more reading on HTML, as this is a pretty basic thing. If you'd spent those 2 hours reading, you'd probably have learned this, plus much more. :-)